# Auto mount webdav folder

Tags: mount, bash, automount, webdav

I want to auto mount webdav folder with bash script. My server resources very pool so I have a memory problem about webdav.
Therefore, I have to umount webdav folder for clear cache and memory. But, I have to manuel mount webdav folders, after than umount command. Because, system ask to me credentail for webdav folder so, I can't do it with bash script.

I edit ~/.davfs/secret file as following format;

```
 http://address username password
```

after than, I uncomment line secrets 
`~/.davfs2/secret` in `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` file.

But, system still ask to me credential information.

How can I auto mount webdav ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Here is an article about that automount https://techiech.blogspot.ch/2013/04/mounting-webdav-directory-in-linux.html.

- Create a folder to mount `sudo mkdir /mnt/dav/`
- Install davfs2 `sudo apt install davfs2`
- Reconfigure it to allow use for unprivileged users `sudo dpkg-reconfigure davfs2`
- Edit `~/.davfs2/secrets` file to add credentials to remote WebDAV directory.

  - Add a line to the end of file in following style:
    `https://<WebDav URI>   <username> <password>`
  - Set the permission:
    `chmod 600 ~/.davfs2/secrets`
- Add a line to `/etc/fstab` like `https://<WebDav URI> /mnt/dav/ davfs user,noauto,file_mode=600,dir_mode=700 0 1`
- Reload systemd `systemctl daemon-reload`
- Add your user to the *davfs2* group
  `sudo usermod -a -G davfs2 your_user`
- Then logout and login again
- That's it. You can use following commands without being a root user to mount with `mount /mnt/dav/`

You can also use nautilus to mount/unmount the directory.

Comment: Cool, this helped me, but can I also automount this folder at boot?

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 I had to: 1. copy /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf to ~/.davfs2 and then edit that file instead (ie uncomment `secret...`) 2. reboot after adding user to davfs2 group.